# Optimize splash screen memory

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, splash-screen

I made a splash screen and then started the activity as usual.

but i noticed that memory usage increased a lot even though i finished the activity and a big difference in memory usage between the splash with a background and the one with no background.

Any solution for this?

a capture of the memory when splash has no background image

[image]

a capture of the memory when splash has a background image

[image]

the code for the splash activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * To get ride of the activity reference to avoid memory leaks
     */
    private static WeakReference<SplashActivity> mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mActivity = new WeakReference<>(this);

        //delay for 2 seconds and start the home activity
        Completable.complete()
                .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .doOnComplete(this::startHomeActivity)
                .subscribe();
    }

    private void startHomeActivity() {
        if (mActivity.get() != null) {
            Activity activity = mActivity.get();
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(activity, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

and set the theme at manifest

```
<style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/zamen_splash</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/splash_color_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What about creating with fragment. it much more lighter

Comment: Are you using any image as a background for that activity ? "zamen_splash" can you tell me the resolution of that drawable ?

Comment: The size of the image?

Comment: @LeandroOcampo no the image come from the style only

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi 1920*1080

Comment: where is that image ? which folder ?

Comment: @LeandroOcampo drawable folder

Comment: I don't see the point in the `WeakReference` - the weak referencing only applies for that variable. If the activity is referenced somewhere else, it'll still remain in memory. You are creating what seems to be a useless reference.

Comment: put that inside drawable-xxxdpi

Comment: @LeandroOcampo what is the diffrenece it's the same

Comment: @VinceEmigh so what should i do

Comment: the difference is that you are telling the SO that the resolution for that image is the one you have an this is for xxx-hdpi resolution. Then Android will adjust that to others resolutions and save you from memory waste.

Comment: I struggled with the same problem a long time ago.

Comment: Seems like Leandro has your answer, I was simply making an observation. You could remove the use of `WeakReference`, as it gives no benefit for how youre using it, and probably doesn't have any use here.

Comment: that's work actullay the memory now is 23mb now istead of 75 thank you very much

Comment: Shall I put my answer then ?

Comment: ok with more explnation will be good

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes weakrefrence has no benefit here

Comment: Garbage Collectors cannot rid of objects that are still in use. `WeakReference` changes this, allowing an object which only has weak references to be GCed. In this case, it's pointless.

Comment: ok i got it thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your drawable inside the specific folder for the resolution your image is being used for.

You said that the image is 1920*1080. So it seem the resolution is for xxx-hdpi. If you put that image inside that specific folder you are telling the SO what the resolution of the phone should be so that it can use that image. In this case xxx-hdpi is for 4x dpi.
This [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) will give you more information.

Then Android will adjust that to others resolutions and save you from memory waste. You can add an specific image for those resolutions inside the other folders (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) and avoid the SO to do the extra work.

Inside this [link](https://material.io/devices/) you will have information for different devices.

As many users said: there is no need of using weakrefrence.